# How do I unit test an instance method dependent on an instance attribute?

Tags: python

I'm in in the process of creating a hangman game. The instance method `resolve_game_status` checks for whether the game should end or continue based on the total number of guesses made. If the game can continue the function will return a string revealing those guessed letters that are a match. The attributes `self.guesses` and `self.game_word` are populated when the class `Game` is instantiated.

So I'm looking to unit test the body of `resolve_game_status`. I'm not sure how to really setup the test in order to achieve this objective given the method is dependent on these two attributes.

````
class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.guesses = []
        self.game_word = choice(game_words)

    def get_player_guess(self):
        pass

    def resolve_game_status(self):
        pass
    '''Access self.guesses & self.game_word from here```
````

```
class TestGameStatus(TestCase):
    '''Verify that the game word string shows only
    those letters that are guessed if the game is ongoing.'''

    def setUp(self):
        self.game = Game()

    def test_hangman_revealed_letter_matches(self):
        with patch.object(
            self.game, 'game_word', new_callable=PropertyMock
        ) as mock_game_word:
            with patch.object(
                self.'guesses', new_callable=PropertyMock
            ) as mock_guesses:
                guesses = [
                    Guess('a', 'miss'), Guess('p', 'hit'), Guess('o', 'hit')
                ]
                mock_game_word.return_value = "python"
                mock_guesses.return_value = guesses
                updated_hangman_string = self.game.resolve_game_status()
                self.assertEqual(updated_hangman_string, "p _ _ _ o _")
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you show? What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't require a random word to be chosen. Create a class method that picks a random word and passes it as an argument to `__init__`.

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self, word):
        self.guesses = []
        self.game_word = word

    @classmethod
    def with_random_word(cls):
        return cls(choice(game_words))

    ...
```

Now you can test by simply passing a known word

```
class TestGameStatus(TestCase):
    '''Verify that the game word string shows only
    those letters that are guessed if the game is ongoing.'''

    def setUp(self):
        self.game = Game("python")

    def test_hangman_revealed_letter_matches(self):
        self.game.guesses = [
                Guess('a', 'miss'), Guess('p', 'hit'), Guess('o', 'hit')
        ]
        updated_hangman_string = self.game.resolve_game_status()
        self.assertEqual(updated_hangman_string, "p _ _ _ o _")
```

Because a new instance of `Game` will be created for each test, there is no need to use `mock.patch` to change the value of `self.guesses`; just assign it directly.

In the real code, you'll simply use `Game.with_random_word()` instead of instantiating `Game` directly.